# Is it possible to use private methods in Angular test (spec) classes?

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have the following test setup in an Angular test class:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MemberListComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  //
  const members = new Map<string, number>();
  members.set('123', 8);
  members.set('456', 9);
  //
  component.members = members;
  fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

Now I would like to move the part between the comments into a private method like so:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MemberListComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  component.members = createMembersMap();
  fixture.detectChanges();
});

private createMembersMap() {
  const members = new Map<string, number>();
  members.set('123', 8);
  members.set('456', 9);
  return members;
}
```

Is this possible? How? I searched the net but all I found was about testing private methods with Angular...

Comment: These tests run procedural code, there is no classes involved in *.spec.ts, so the concept of private methods doesn't really apply here. Just replace the word `private` with `function` and you should get the expected result.

Comment: Sure, you can extract the logic to a separate function but why private access modifier?
As jasmine test cases execute as closure functions IMO we do not need any access modifiers here. You can simply use function createMembersMap() {} directly.

Comment: Thanks to user776686 and Ravi. That is exactly what I wanted! Didn't know that private does not apply in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Behind the scene, it is javascript with nothing private.
It is a smell to call private methods in tests. It would be better to consider change it to public or test it together with a function that use that private method.